# get row data from data gridview on vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net

I want get data from 1 row of a `DataGridView`, I select to my textbox
this is my code,

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged

    Dim dColums(0) As DataColumn
    dColums(0) = dsetmember.Tables("member").Columns(0)
    dsetmember.Tables("member").PrimaryKey = dColums

    'MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 1)
    If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = -1 Then
        txtNamaMember.Text = ""
        txtKodeMember.Text = ""
        txtNoHP.Text = ""
    Else
        Dim dr As DataRow = dsetmember.Tables("member").Rows.Find(DataGridView1.Item(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 0))
        txtKodeMember.Text = dr(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

I get this error, `nullreferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

thx b4.

Comment: Could you tell us on which line this exception is raised?

Comment: still can't run the program steve, can u more help me

Comment: Use the debugger, place a breakpoint inside this function and then step by step (see the debug menu) tell us where the exception kicks

Comment: @yusli: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for this site. Especially: Please write your question in a generic way so that other people can also get benefit from the work of the answerers. Also: Please be specific about your problem. A simple "something does not work, please help" is not appropriate. So if someone asks for details, then please deliver these details. Also: Please note that this is __not__ a chat site. This mean, that a) plain English is preferred and b) that you should provide information upfront and not piece by piece.

Comment: error on txtkodemember.text = dr(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this part ..

```
If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = -1 Then
    txtNamaMember.Text = ""
    txtKodeMember.Text = ""
    txtNoHP.Text = ""
Else
    Dim dr As DataRow = dsetmember.Tables("member").Rows.Find(DataGridView1.Item(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 0))
    txtKodeMember.Text = dr.item(0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in the assigniment of dr(0) to the textbox.Text.
This means that the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx) method has not found the value passed and so the result is NULL.
Trying to reference `dr(0)` when dr is Nothing is like writing NOTHING(0) and, of course, this will fail

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dsetmember.Tables("member").Rows.Find(DataGridView1.Item(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 0))
if dr IsNot Nothing then
    txtKodeMember.Text = dr(0)
else
    MessageBox.Show("Value not found")
End If
```

Also remember that the Find method search the value passed on the primary key column(s) of the table. Are you sure that the first column of the grid contains the primary keys?